# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed - Url rewrite not working

Tags: .net, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a 405 error on a website and trying to reproduce that issue locally on my machine. Unfortunately the error is happening on the UAT enviornment and 
not having access to it.

The error is happening because the website is called with a POST request from a third party vendor website.  I need to be able to track that request and convert it 
to get.  I able to reproduce it when i call the url http://test.com/analysis as a POST request.
I have tried applying the following url rewrite on but it doesnt seem to recognize it. All I am trying to is convert the POST request to GET

**Error Message**

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Requested URL   http://test.com:80/index.html
Please note that http://test.com:80/index.html finally calls http://test.com/analysis

The rule that i have written to intercept the post and redirect it to load the site as get

```
    <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="*" />
       <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="analysis" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
         <action  type="Redirect" url="http://test.com/analysis" />
    </rule>
```